# Plot Clustered Data by kmeans with colors for clusters and shapes for external labels

Tags: k-means, python-3.x, plotting

I wrote some Python code that uses the output from a principal component analysis to perform k-means on.  The output to my script below is

> Cluster 1: Data Points: [[ 1.87192346 -1.12568277]  [ 1.97012514
> -0.70532312]  [ 3.45778709 -0.64678024]  [ 2.61029111 -2.32216733]] Center: [ 2.4775317  -1.19998837]
>
> Cluster 2: Data Points: [[-3.22914198  0.47263998]  [-2.21336465
> -0.30760444]  [-2.46006546 -0.30036711]  [-1.39971878 -0.56487664]  [-2.68357487 -0.4820239 ]  [-1.75873004 -0.12933835]  [-1.20901232
> -0.97706353]  [-1.4371756   0.58947658]] Center: [-2.04884796 -0.21239468]
>
> Cluster 3: Data Points: [[ 0.84583072  0.10252569]  [ 0.17431096
> 0.05538357]  [ 0.85267424 -0.37199898]  [ 1.4510463   0.56553754]  [ 0.67175039  0.39289585]  [ 0.24957358 -0.11225323]  [ 0.76510952 -0.4331749 ]  [-0.36521848  0.61189523]  [-0.31164943  1.31746906]] Center: [0.48149198 0.23647554]
>
> Cluster 4: Data Points: [[2.1472291  4.37083105]] Center: [2.1472291
> 4.37083105]

Additionally, a plot is drawn, the clusters are colored, and the cluster centers are marked with a red x.  I wanted all of this, but I have an additional column with categorical labels to the data and I want to shape my data points according to the respective category.  For example,

```
shape_markers = {
    'Group 1': 's',  # Square
    'Group 2': 'o',  # Circle
    'Group 3': '^',  # Triangle
    'Group 4': 'v',  # Inverted Triangle
    'Group 5': 'd'  # Diamond
}
```

There are the clusters determined by the k-means algorithm then there are the labels I want to superimpose on the data.  So, for example, we could imagine a blue data point that could be a circle or could be a triangle depending on its given label before and independent of the kmeans algorithm (which did determine the point belongs to the blue cluster).  Here I am using 5 groups and 4 clusters (there's no reason to assume these need to be equal).  The data array output from PCA is pca_data and is the numerical component of the dataframe, df, which has an additional column, Group, such that elements of Group are 'Group 1', ...., and 'Group 5'. How can I modify my code below to superimpose the shapes on the data according to the group labels and add a key to the plot to associate shapes with their Group value?

```
# Specify the number of clusters
k = 4

# Create a KMeans instance
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k, init = 'random', n_init = 'auto')


# Fit the KMeans model to the data
kmeans.fit(pca_data)

# Get the cluster labels for each data point
labels = kmeans.labels_

# Get the cluster centers
centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_

# Print the cluster labels and centers
for i in range(k):
    cluster_points = pca_data[labels == i]
    cluster_center = centers[i]
    print(f"Cluster {i+1}:")
    print(f"Data Points: {cluster_points}")
    print(f"Center: {cluster_center}")
    print()

# Visualize the clusters 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(pca_data[:, 0], pca_data[:, 1], c=labels)
plt.scatter(centers[:, 0], centers[:, 1], marker='X', color='red')
plt.xlabel('X-coordinate')
plt.ylabel('Y-coordinate')
plt.title('K-means Clustering')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say in your pca_data list, every next element after x and y coordinate is their class label or Group name. Something like this... pca_data = [x1, y1, 'Group 1', x2, y2, 'Group 2', ....]. 
*I have taken random points to make pca_data list.*  

You can use the code below for plotting data points.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import OrderedDict

pca_data = [1.87192346, -1.12568277, 'Group 1', 1.97012514, -0.70532312, 'Group 2',  3.45778709, -0.64678024, 'Group 2', 2.61029111, -2.32216733, 'Group 3', 0.84583072, 0.10252569, 'Group 1',0.17431096, 0.05538357, 'Group 2', 0.85267424, -0.37199898, 'Group 2',1.4510463, 0.56553754, 'Group 3', 0.67175039, 0.39289585, 'Group 1', 0.24957358, -0.11225323, 'Group 2',0.76510952, -0.4331749, 'Group 2',-0.36521848, 0.61189523, 'Group 1', -0.31164943, 1.31746906, 'Group 1']

# Lists of groups, shapes and colors
groups = ['Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 3', 'Group 4', 'Group 5']
shapes = ['s', 'o', '^', 'v', 'd']
colors = ['pink', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'brown']

i = 0
while (i<len(pca_data)-1):
    g = pca_data[i+2]  
    idx = int(g[-1]) - 1;  # Geting the shape and group index, e.g., for Group 1, the shape is at 0th index.
    group = groups[idx] # Getting the group name
    plt.scatter(pca_data[i], pca_data[i+1], marker = shapes[idx], label= group, color = colors[idx])
    i+=3

handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()  
by_label = OrderedDict(zip(labels, handles))    # adding label values to dict to remove duplicate legend values
plt.legend(by_label.values(), by_label.keys())
plt.show()
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6Rmm.png): [image: Scatter plot]

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for the help!